# Android FragmentActivity Unable to start activity: NullPointerException at re-launch

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

My app's main activity extends FragmentActivity and functions correctly when Paused and Resumed by shifting to other Apps on phone.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ..
    .
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(PAGE_No / 2);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_pager, container, false);
    ...
    ..
    .    
    mGridView.setAdapter(new CellAdapter(rootView.getContext(), x,y));
    return rootView;
}
```

However, when it is killed by ActivityManager (ActivityManager: Process com.androcn.aaa.bbb (pid 16471) has died.) I receive: **Unable to start activity: NullPointerException**, from compiler once re-launch it:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androcn.aaa.bbb/com.androcn.aaa.bbb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.androcn.aaa.bbb.MainActivity$MonthViewFragment.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1856)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:210)
    at com.androcn.aaa.bbb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    ... 11 more
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me about this.

Comment: The log says: at com.androcn.aaa.bbb.MainActivity$MonthViewFragment.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162). So what line of code is at MainActivity.java:162?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, my theme setting code was the problem: `context.setTheme(.....);`